# Twillio Hangs Up After Recording

Tags: xml, twilio

My XML

```
    <Record maxLength="30" finishOnKey="#" />
    <Say>The recording failed</Say>
```

And I have code that catches the 'RecordingUrl' parameter and outputs different XML to handle the action on the same page. The issue is no matter what i do, let it run the 30 sec or hit pound the call just hangs up, neither the action call or the failed say tag gets run.

The recording is saved when i log in to my account, so it is recording and it is saving it.

The url to see the XML, https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php

change the parameters and you will get different XML

Ex:

https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?From=+16148999999

https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?Digits=2

//this is where it hangs up when it should call

https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?RecordingUrl=http://linktorec

Comment: Could you show the full code so we can see what might be going on around this. Thanks

Comment: I don't know your parameters, could you post the code (or more of the code at least) so we can see what's actually going on?

Comment: the parameters are all determined by Twillio in the docs. Initially no parameters passed in (or the phone number as the var From) then a get/post with var Digits (depending which number was selected) then if it was a recording it should have a var called RecordingUrl that is post/get. All these are appended to the same URL. For example https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?From=+16148999999

Comment: That may be, but it's easiest to see what may or may not go wrong by looking at your code. As this is a programming forum, perhaps you could help us to help you and show us some of the code you have written.

Comment: I could post the code, but that really doesn't matter, Twillio uses XML to run, why would the code that generates the XML (as long as the XML is correct) matter? Using those links in the question you can see all the XML I output. Its very simple PHP code that checks the variable to determine which output to present. I don't have the code with me now, but I can post it tonight.

Comment: Hey Osman, the XML does look right, that's why it would seem like a good idea to post the code to make sure that everything else looks right, I don't think I can help any more unless I see it! Do you have logging that shows whether the URL gets called again after the `<Record>` at all?

Comment: Actually, I think I've got something! Answer coming up now.

Comment: Really sorry slipped my mind to post the code, looking into your solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the issue is down to what you're looking for to route calls within your code. To get to the recording TwiML you need to have entered 2 on the keypad with the previous `<Gather>`. Then you are looking for the `Digits` parameter to set up the next action.

- https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?Digits=1 tries to `<Dial>`
- https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?Digits=2 sends to `<Record>`
- https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?Digits=[ANYTHING_ELSE] produces an empty `<Response>` tag

When you finish a recording, Twilio makes a call to the action with three particular parameters, `RecordingUrl`, `RecordingDuration` and ***`Digits`***.

My guess is that you are checking for the `Digits` parameter before you check for `RecordingUrl` and that your call is being hung up because you are returning an empty `<Response>` instead of the TwiML you expect. Like this:

https://aliahealthcare.com/api/twilo.php?RecordingUrl=http://linktorec&Digits=#

Rather than maintain a giant conditional based on incoming parameters, it might be easier to split this application into a few files and explicitly set actions for the `<Gather>` and `<Record>` verbs.

Let me know if this helps!